# Creation of correlated marks. E.g. point sizes varying with inter-point distances

Tags: r, spatstat

I recently dabbled a bit into point pattern analysis and wonder if there is any standard practice to create mark correlation structures varying with the inter-point distance of point locations. Clearly, I understand how to simulate independent marks, as it is frequently mentioned e.g.

```
library(spatstat)
data(finpines) 
set.seed(0907)
marks(finpines) <- rnorm(npoints(finpines), 30, 5)
plot(finpines)
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R3kmb.png)

More generally speaking, assume we have a fair amount of points, say n=100 with coordinates x and y in an arbitrary observation window (e.g. rectangle). Every point carries a characteristic, for example the size of the point as a continuous variable. Also, we can examine every pairwise distance between the points. Is there a way to introduce correlation structure between the marks (of pairs of points) which depends on the inter-point distance between the point locations?

---

Furthermore, I am aware of the existence of mark analysing techniques like

```
fin <- markcorr(finpines, correction = "best")
plot(fin)
```

When it comes to interpretation, my lack of knowledge forces me to trust my colleagues (non-scientists). Besides, I looked at several references given in the documentation of the `spatstat` functions; especially, I had a look on "[Statistical Analysis and Modelling of Spatial Point Patterns](https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/book/10.1002/9780470725160)", p. 347, where inhibition and mutual stimulation as deviations from 1 (independence of marks) of the normalised mark correlation function are explained.

Answer (score 1):

I think the best bet is to use a random field model conditional on your locations. Unfortunately the package `RandomFields` is not on CRAN at the moment, but hopefully it will return soon. I think it may be possible to install an old version of `RandomFields` from the archives if you want to get going immediately.

Thus, the procedure is:

1. Use `spatstat` to generate the random locations you like.
2. Extract the coordinates (either `coords()` or `as.data.frame.ppp()`).
3. Define a model in `RandomFields` (e.g. `RMexp()`).
4. Simulate the model on the given coordinates (`RFsimulate()`).
5. Convert back to a marked point pattern in spatstat (either `ppp()` or `as.ppp()`).

Comment: Thank you very much! I will try to get it going soon! Not sure how to set up such a model yet (cp. bullet point 3).

Comment: Unfortunately, found no way to install `{RandomFields}` from the archives on arm64 (apple silicon).

Comment: Maybe you could try to install from https://predictiveecology.r-universe.dev (I don't know if it works on Apple Silicon):
`install.packages(c("RandomFieldsUtils", "RandomFields"), repos = "https://predictiveecology.r-universe.dev")`

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. Tried similar approaches; error. I think Apple Silicon is the problem with those.

Comment: OK. Did you also try to compile an old version locally? E.g. installing `RandomFieldsUtils_0.5.5.tar.gz` from https://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/Archive/RandomFieldsUtils/ and `RandomFields_3.3.13.tar.gz` from https://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/Archive/RandomFields/ ? Is the compilation of the package C-code giving an error on Apple Silicon?

Comment: Indeed, I tried. Installation of `RandomFieldUtils` works without throwing any error, but for `RandomField`: `ERROR: compilation failed for package` + warning: `had non-zero exit status`. Even after installing XCode.

Comment: Asking for curiosity, would it be possible to add some explanation to 3-6?  `xy <- coords(finpines); model <- RMexp(); res <- RFsimulate(model = model, x = xy);
marks(finpines) <- res$variable1`  Is this the suggested way? Is there a way to construct correlated marks on the positive axis only?